# rails/info/routes template is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a rails 4.2 app and I was wondering why my app is missing the rails/info/routes template and if it's possible to recreate it somehow.

"rake routes" works, but I was hoping to have use that template too.

I get the following error when I visit http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

```
Missing partial routes/_route with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], 
:variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
Searched in: *"/home/tquill/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-
2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * 
"/home/tquill/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-
4.2.5.1/lib/rails/templates"
```

Thanks.

Comment: it is missing your partial, not template

Comment: Do you know where that routes partial is stored?  It works in my other app, but I didn't see it when I searched its directory.

Comment: did you ever get this working, i am getting this error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem on my app.  It was because i was using the web-console gem:

```
gem 'web-console'
```

removing that shows my routes again

Comment: Thanks.  I had no idea that was causing the issues.  I actually just updated the gem from 2.0.0.beta3 to the latest (3.1.1) and the routes url works now.